# "Temporary failure in name resolution"/ DNS Error in Kali (VMWare) / Slow Kali Download

Tags: kali-linux, dns, vmware

I was doing some pinging on Kali (on VMWare) and realised that I could only ping IP addresses.

*Pinging 8.8.8.8 WORKS*

BUT pinging google.com either **takes too long** or gives an error: **"Temporary failure in name resolution"**

Amending the /etc/resolv.conf file by adding more DNS servers (nameservers) and changing permissions to 644 does not work. Furthermore, it's not really permanent because a restart would change the configuration.

Downloading speed on Kali has been really slow too.

What's the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was actually simple than I thought (only on VMWare, but you can check if the same solution works for VirtualBox).

In VMWare, under the tab, go to Edit > Virtual Network Editor.

1. Authorise "Change Settings"
2. Select your adapter, if you're using NAT, it's most likely VMnet8.
3. Click NAT Settings
4. Click DNS Settings
5. Uncheck "Auto detect available DNS servers"
6. Add DNS Servers (Refer to: https://www.hpe.com/us/en/insights/articles/get-faster-internet-with-better-dns-1909.html)

I use the following:

[image: Preferred DNS Servers]

Answer (score -1):

Some DNS servers cannot properly handle parallel requests. Then you need to configure single-request option in your resolv.conf. See man page. It helped in my case. I added such line:

```
options single-request
```

Answer (score -1):

on kali try this:
go into /etc/network/if-up.d
and open the file "resolved" with some text editor.
you will found a part of the script with DNS=DNS, change it to DNS=8.8.8.8 and its done, at least it worked for me.[image]

Comment: you can also change resolv.conf by adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 and restart systemd-resolve but on my case i coud't bcs i kept getting an error of none existent service :/ Feel free to share this information with others if it works for you too :D

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Doesn't seem to be necessary - like the OP I'm running Kali on a VM, I've not modified my `resolved` file i.e. it says **DNS=DNS** and I have no problems with DNS. You should [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742458/edit) the question to explain why OP should touch this file - expecially since they [resolved the issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/695925/90878) by correcting the hypervisor settings.

Comment: That looks a really bad idea. You're changing a definition that ends up as something like  `DNS=1.2.3.4` (where `1.2.3.4` is a discovered DNS server) to `8.8.8.8=1.2.3.4`. Now if you'd advised changing the `NEW_DNS` assignment I'd have moved on, as that could be plausible